# setOnCheckedChangeListener is never called

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog, radio-group

I am trying all day to understand, why my method setOnChangeListener is never called...it works well until the first Toast...The second toast never appear. What is wrong? Should i pass someway the view to the onCheckedChangeListener? I have activity, where user can click on button, then he get alertdialog, with 3 radio buttons and radiogroup inside. I want to get, what radiobutton he has choosen. No matter what i tried. Nothing worked. I get always only the one radio button as checked, which i checked in xml layout...Help...

```
Button setWeekType = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setWeekType);
    if (setWeekType != null) {
        setWeekType.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(report_activity.this, R.style.DialogTheme)
                        .setView(R.layout.dialog_type_day)
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Choose", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                final View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_type_day, null);
                                final RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup)child.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
                                final RadioButton bhome = (RadioButton)child.findViewById(R.id.bhome);
                                final RadioButton bwork = (RadioButton)child.findViewById(R.id.bwork);
                                final RadioButton bschool = (RadioButton)child.findViewById(R.id.bschool);
                                bwork.setChecked(true);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        if (checkedId == bhome.getId()) {
                                            bhome.setChecked(true);
                                        }if (checkedId == bwork.getId()) {
                                            bwork.setChecked(true);
                                        }if (checkedId == bschool.getId()) {
                                            bschool.setChecked(true);
                                        }

                                    }

                                });

                            }

                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .show();





            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Show method of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run your code and I think the problem is with `child` View, It's `null`! So `radiogroup` is `null` too and the `listener` will never be set, Use logging to see yourself.

I recommend you to create a custom `DialogFragment` to get rid of nested inner classes and manage things much more easier.

In case you need a tutorial: 
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-dialogfragment-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can make that to else if. Example :

```
if (checkedId == bhome.getId()) {
    bhome.setChecked(true);
}else if (checkedId == bwork.getId()) {
    bwork.setChecked(true);
}else if (checkedId == bschool.getId()) {
     bschool.setChecked(true);
}
```

And you can make oncheckedchangelistener in a top of on click listener

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setOnCheckedChangeListener` from within the (positive) button callback. This means that your second Toast can only be shown after the user has already clicked the "Choose" button (which presumably, is too late).

You need to get the find the radio group from the AlertDialog instance and call `setOnCheckedChangeListener` before you show the dialog.

Comment: Can you give simple hint where to put the setOnCheckedChangeListener? I tried to do it before the alert dialog but, it is wrong too. Small snippet would be enough. Thanks for help!